# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map; JIRA REST client

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jira-rest-api

I am getting the following error when try to get Issues from JIRA using JIRA Rest client.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

Below the pom i am using.

```xml
<properties>
    <jersey-2-version>2.29</jersey-2-version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
        <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am trying to fetch issues and return it through a rest api.

```
  SearchResult searchJqlPromise =restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql("issuetype = Bug AND resolution  = Unresolved ORDER BY created DESC%2C priority DESC%2C updated DESC").claim();
    entity = new GenericEntity<Iterable<Issue>>(searchJqlPromise.getIssues())
        {
        };
```

Can someone post me the exact versions of JSon and other libraries to be used.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the `mvn dependency:tree` command?

Comment: output is too long to fit in comment

Comment: Not a problem. Could you please add it to the question itself (edit the question)?

Comment: Plz post the complete exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the latest version and check ?
You can use the following dependencies in maven pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

References
You can refer below the links in mvnrepository.com.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core/5.1.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-api/5.1.0

Comment: I get this when i use latest version

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:307)
  
 
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293)
 org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
 org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)

Comment: This error is not related to Atlassian library, can post the rest point details so that I can check.

Comment: I have updated the code with latest version details and current error i am getting